# Is it possible to know whether an arbitrary system is performing a quantum computation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-computer

Without knowing in advance that a physical system has been configured to do so, is it possible to determine whether that system is preforming, or has just performed a quantum computation?

That is, if I have an arbitrary system, $\mathbf{S}$, are there any

- observations I can make on $\mathbf{S}$ which would tell me that it is currently preforming a quantum computation; or
- are there any changes to the environment containing $\mathbf{S}$ which would indicate that that environment has observed the "output" (performed a measurement on) a system that had been preforming a quantum computation?

Or is there perhaps some other way?

Comment: Define "quantum computation." No, seriously, because depending on how you do so you might say that every system is always doing a quantum computation of its own dynamics.

Comment: To give a different perspective on @Rococo's comment, how would you determine is an arbitrary classical system is performing classical computation?

Comment: @Rococo: Good point. I guess that suggests (as _By Symmetry_) implies, that the answer is no: "doing a quantum computing" in the sense of the question (if it means anything) means that S is undergoing some evolution in the absence of any observation by the system of which the observer is a part. The question is effectively like asking whether it is possible to determine that S is or has been totally isolated (at least with respect to properties of S that are subsequently observed).